# Identifying manufacturer (brand) of toilet from a photograph

Tags: toilet

Can anyone identify the manufacturer of the toilet from the following photograph? It is the original toilet installed by KB Home in 2007.

[image]

I am guessing it is made by American Standard. Is that correct?

Reason I ask is because I don’t have access to the toilet for a few weeks, and I’d like to browse for a few parts for it in the meantime. I’m guessing it is American Standard because it’s commonly used by home builders, and it does look similar to images I found of American Standard toilets on the manufacturer’s website as well as Google Images.

Comment: If there are absolutely no markings, then it's a no-brand generic and your chances of finding parts for it are slim to nil.

Comment: There are usually stamps or casting marks. Many toilets look the same from 10' away. I have an American Standard that looks just like this. My last home had Kolher "high flush" that could take 25-35 golf balls in one flush that looked the same or similar.

Comment: Since your edit mentioned American Standard, does it have those marks? Next question is... what are you trying to accomplish by knowing?

Comment: Ask a question specific to the problem you're trying to solve. Surely it's not just a matter of curiosity. The question is somewhat off-topic for DIYSE as it stands.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I know American Standard is pretty commonly used by builders, so I just browsed some pics from Google images, as well as the American Standard website, and it looked similar. If I can find out the manufacturer, I'd like to browse for a few parts for it (don't have access to the toilet at the moment).

Comment: Most of the manufacturers place their name either near or between the bolts that hold the seat on, odd that there is none there. I think I may have seen American Standard place theirs on the left side of the bowl near the tank mount. A lot of the internals of toilets that are the age of yours are standardized. Not until recent the toilets got more water saving intense with valves that half flush, that is where you need to be aware of the internals.

Comment: There's no way to tell from THAT photograph.

Comment: I just looked at the toilet in my apartment and it looks like the one in the photo. But, it's made by Peerless Pottery. So, I realize now that the photo doesn't help. I'll go ahead and delete the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand the reasoning behind your question but you should never "browse" for parts without first laying eyes on the parts you need, unless you like bringing/sending them back. There are numerous manufacturers with models that look just like this. Even if your wild guess is correct, manufacturers use different internals for the same tank and bowl depending on model. They also change internals year to year but continue to use the same tanks and bowls.

Wait until you return and you will find manufacturer and model information stamped into the back of the tank. More importantly you will be able to see the parts you need.